# Migrating Laravel packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have got a project on its middle way. The person use something like this to create
a directory structure in the app folder:

```
php artisan myProject:plugin --create="sample"
```

And then this command creates a directory structure. This directory is like this:

```
./app/
     plugins/
             models
             controller
             views
             migrations
```

Now, I don't know how should I make news migrations or migrate the current migration files
which I have applied some changes to. What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your application is already in production, you must always create new migrations, because you cannot rollback migrations in production or you will loose data. So create a new migration for every little modification you need to do in your database tables.

Comment: well, that's my problem already. I cannot create new migrations and I don't know how should do it. I use --path flag, but it persistently keeps throwing exception that file is not found (while there is just path and no file, and the file should be created by laravel itself)

Comment: Out from here, I'm afraid we cannot really help you without seeing a lot of the code. But you can always create Laravel migrations manually in that folder, they are simple PHP file classes.